# WordPress - No Background Images on Live Server

Tags: wordpress, background-image

I am having tons of trouble with this issue. I'm taking a WordPress course, and I'm on the final part... moving it from my localhost to a live server.

After doing so, however, my background images do not appear. At first, my whole media library was broken, but I was able to fix that. I can't seem to figure out the issue with the background images though.

I've been scouring multiple forums looking for an answer before posting here... but I can't seem to find it, or understand it, so I thought I'd ask for help regarding my specific situation.

Here is a link to the current, live WordPress site: http://176.32.230.251/znbootstraptowordpress.com/

And here is a link to the static site, so you can see what background images are missing:
http://176.32.230.251/b2wzachnagatani.com/

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your style.css on /themes/bootsrap2wordpress/style.css

find `/wp-content/themes/bootsrap2wordpress/assets/img/` 
there and replace all with

```
./assets/img/
```

Your problem will be solved .

[full css](http://jsfiddle.net/lemonkazi/5mfsbeju/)

Comment: Almost. This helped me figure it out though. I needed to do a search and replace... but I put assets/img/ , not .../img/ , and it worked. Thank you very much for leading me in the right direction.

Comment: I also suggested u to put ./assets/img/

Comment: See my link http://jsfiddle.net/lemonkazi/5mfsbeju/ there I updated ur css.

Comment: @ZachNagatani you can accept the answer rather than saying >>thank you<< in comment

Comment: Accepted your answer, but the period before /assets is unnecessary, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your problem:

```
#hero {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("/wp-content/themes/bootsrap2wordpress/assets/img/hero-bg.jpg") repeat fixed 50% 0;
    color: white;
    min-height: 500px;
    padding: 40px 0;
    text-rendering: optimizelegibility;
}
```

url path is incorrect so the browser cant find the image in the path specificed on css ... thats the problem.

Here is the correct path (taken from the page where the background image shows):

```
#hero {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("../img/hero-bg.jpg") repeat fixed 50% 0;
    color: white;
    min-height: 500px;
    padding: 40px 0;
    text-rendering: optimizelegibility;
}
```

Use Firebug to inspect the element, it helps a lot in this cases to find the root of a problem.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but I don't think that's the issue. The URLs are different because one is just a static site, and one is integrated into WordPress. I tried changing it anyway, to no avail.

Comment: That is an issue though. I checked with firebug and the browser cant render that image because it cant find it. So there is a path problem there ... and that needs to be fixed.

Comment: The problem is with your image path ... now normaly its not the path i specified as the correct one since its static site path but there definitely is a problem with the path and that needs to be fixed before proceeding checking other things.

Comment: Gotchya. Sorry, I was referring to the statement that the other one was the correct path. The idea that it IS the image path I can definitely see. I'll have to try and figure that out.

I am super new to WP... I just don't understand why it works on the localhost but not the live server?

Comment: Here is the path:

http://176.32.230.251/znbootstraptowordpress.com/wp-content/themes/bootsrap2wordpress/assets/img/hero-bg.jpg

Dont forget to upvote my solution and mark it as solved if it solved your problem.