# Some images not showing on live wordpress website

Tags: css, wordpress

I was developing a site on my localhost but when I upload it on a live server, some images are not showing.

The local version of the background image's CSS code is this:

```
   rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("/wp-content/themes/school/assets/img/_EL18466.jpg") repeat fixed 50% 0 / cover
```

The live version of the image is:

```
rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("/wp-content/themes/school/assets/img/_EL18466.jpg") repeat fixed 50% 0 / cover;
```

Basically, its just the same line of code for both local and live version.

However the image on the live version is not displaying. Whats wrong? Should the URL be different on the live one?

TIA

EDIT:

Here is the screenshot of my live server's directory structure:

[image: Server screenshot]

Comment: take a look in your developer console from your browser, does it show errors? those errors will point you in the right direction

Comment: @Christophvh nothing related to css image errors was displayed on Console. its more of the javascript and Ip address of my test server

Comment: What is the page directory that has the link for the image to display on?

Comment: Under wp-content->themes->school-assets->img

Comment: Withou seeing more code its not really alot anyone can do to help as it is so broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer to this grueling bug

[WordPress - No Background Images on Live Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32920346/wordpress-no-background-images-on-live-server)

Apparently, when its on live server, the background css image code should only be:

```
rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("./assets/img/_EL18466.jpg") repeat fixed 50% 0 / cover;
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your css is in folder assets, so you are calling image from css, and if you have img folder then you must write like this:

```
rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("../assets/img/_EL18466.jpg") repeat fixed 50% 0 / cover;
```

You must get out from css folder and then go to img and call that jpg, that is why you have ../img/image.jpg

Comment: Still not working. The css file is inside the school folder under themes

Comment: Do you have live link so i can see that issue?

Comment: I'm can't send it publicly. Sorry

Comment: Still no :( . Just would like to repeat - the css file is under the school folder.

Comment: No luck still. I'm guessing this is not a link issue?

Comment: It's issue with path in your css, i cant see all what you have there.

Comment: can you provide a screenshot of your directory on your server, this will help diagnose it, it is most likely the url

Answer (score 0):

Okay, After looking at the screenshot you provided, and a little bit of thought.
If it is the index file you are loading the image on to (presumption)
then for the URL try this:

> rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)
>   url(assets/img/_EL18466.jpg) repeat fixed
>   50% 0 / cover;

All i have done here is taken out the / at the beginning, and the quotes in the url itself.
If it works, then it is because the page you are loading it onto is in the same directory as the wp-content, and the image URL may be looking to go up to the root folder.

As an afterthought, if that doesnt work, just to check as i can't see it there.
you have tried using:

```
<img src="assets/img/_EL18466.jpg">
```

Or for the CSS:

```
content: url(assets/img/_EL18466.jpg);
```

Comment: Are you able to provide more code from both pages, maybe do a snippet?

Comment: I just found my answer here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32920346/wordpress-no-background-images-on-live-server

Comment: you were close though